# Inserting multiple same values in PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sql-insert, asyncpg

I've searched around and couldn't find a solution for my question - I want to insert multiple of the same values in a table?

For example, I'm using Asyncpg for python, I would do something like this:

```
for i in range(5):
  await execute("INSERT INTO table (column_a, column_b) VALUES (1, 2)")
```

while using a sequence to create unique "ID's" for each row. I understand you can use multiple values, but I want to make it so it's an arbitrary amount, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: I can't really understand what you want to do. What would be the expected result? 5 rows with the same values (1, 2)?

Comment: Yes, basically inserting a table with 5 rows with the same values.

Comment: Remove the `WHERE` section. Use: `INSERT INTO table (column_a, column_b) VALUES (1, 2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres, you can insert 5 rows at once with a single query using `generate_series()`:

```
insert into mytable (column_a, column_b) 
select 1, 2
from generate_series(1, 5);
```